# undo method of UndoManager execute number of times the registerUndo while testing

Tags: swift, testing, xctest

I called undoMethod from the TestClass only once. But undo method executed number of times the registerUndo.

this is my test class.

```
import XCTest
@testable import UnitTestProject

class UnitTestProjectTests: XCTestCase {

    func testUndo() {
        let model = TestModel()
        
        model.increment()
        XCTAssertEqual(model.count, 1)
        
        model.increment()
        XCTAssertEqual(model.count, 2)
        
        model.increment()
        XCTAssertEqual(model.count, 3)
        
        model.undo()
        XCTAssertEqual(model.count, 2)
        
    }
}
```

and this is target class.

```
import Foundation

class TestModel {
    
    let undoManager = UndoManager()
    var count = 0
    
    func registerUndo() {
        if (undoManager.isUndoRegistrationEnabled) {
            undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { _ in
                print("undo is executed")
                self.count -= 1
            })
        }
    }
    
    func increment() {
        count += 1
        registerUndo()
    }
    
    func undo() {
        if(undoManager.canUndo){
            undoManager.undo()
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, this test code called undo method only once. But undo method actually called three times, so this test will fail.

```
this is console log
Test Case '-[UnitTestProjectTests.UnitTestProjectTests testUndo]' started.
undo is executed
undo is executed
undo is executed
/Users/project/UnitTestProject/UnitTestProjectTests/UnitTestProjectTests.swift:27: error: -[UnitTestProjectTests.UnitTestProjectTests testUndo] : XCTAssertEqual failed: ("0") is not equal to ("2")
Test Case '-[UnitTestProjectTests.UnitTestProjectTests testUndo]' failed (0.019 seconds).
Test Suite 'UnitTestProjectTests' failed at 2021-01-04 22:21:43.585.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.019 (0.020) seconds
Test Suite 'UnitTestProjectTests.xctest' failed at 2021-01-04 22:21:43.585.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.019 (0.021) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2021-01-04 22:21:43.586.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.019 (0.023) seconds
```

I would like to ask the following 2 points.

・Why this undo method executed number of times the registerUndo while testing?

・How to test Undo and Redo method like this?

Finally, thank you for your thinking for this question what written in poor English.

Answer (score 5):

By default, undoManager groups all actions that are executed during a same runloop cycle. In your example, you execute three consecutive actions, therefore these three actions constitute a single group in the undoManager stack. At undo time, the three actions are reverted at a time and this is why you see that the handler block is called three times rather than one.

You can change the default behavior, but at the cost of managing grouping yourself, because any action, even a single one, must be enclosed in a group. I give you an example but please take into account that I'm an objective-c user and have no practice of swift (fortunately the syntax here is pretty simple).

First, you should deactivate the default behavior which is to group actions automatically :

```
 undoManager.groupsByEvent = false
```

Then each call to registerUndo should be surrounded by a call to beginUndoGrouping and endUndoGrouping (which could be simplified using a dedicated function) :

```
undoManager.beginUndoGrouping()
undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { _ in
            print("undo is executed")
            self.count -= 1
        })
undoManager.endUndoGrouping()
```

Now, you will have to call undo three times to get the same result than in your example and you should be able to break down your tests more simply.

Comment: Thanks to you, I was helped!!
My tests succeeded!